# Is the includeFile() Method necessary?

Tags: composer-php

I'm just curious that why don`t official team use ***include $file;*** directly in ClassLoader.php ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [code docs](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L442) are pretty clear about that:

```
/**
 * Scope isolated include.
 *
 * Prevents access to $this/self from included files.
 */
function includeFile($file)
{
    include $file;
}
```

It isolates the loading code so it can't access `$this` or `$self`.